# Regex is not handling chr(10) character

Tags: oracle

```sql
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR (
        str,
        '(.*?)(~-delim~-|$)',
        1,
        LEVEL,
        NULL,
        1
    ) output
FROM (
    SELECT 'Line1~-delim~-Line2' AS str FROM DUAL
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (str, '~-delim~-') + 1
```

Output is

```
Line1
Line2
```

```sql
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR (
        str,
        '(.*?)(~-delim~-|$)',
        1,
        LEVEL,
        NULL,
        1
    ) output
FROM (
    SELECT 'Line1'||chr(10)||'~-delim~-Line2' AS str FROM DUAL
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (str, '~-delim~-') + 1
```

Output is

```
Line2
```

Why the the newline is causing the string to suffer? I would expect the output to be:

```
Line1

Line2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the Oracle regexp engine does not match the wildcard `.` to the newline character (`chr(10)`).

You can change that behavior by using the fifth argument to `regexp_substr`. Currently you assigned `null` to it. Change that to `'n'` (including the single-quotes) and try again. You will get what you need.

Then check the documentation for `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, specifically about the fifth parameter - you will see what other options are available. You may not need them now, but perhaps you will remember them when you need them in the future.

Comment: This does not work for chr(10) as requested by the title:

SELECT level,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR (
        str,
        '(.*?)($)',
        1,
        LEVEL,
        'n',
        1
    ) output
FROM (
    SELECT 'Line1'||chr(13) ||'Line2' AS str FROM DUAL
)    returns                 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (str, chr(10)) + 1;



returns  
"Line1
Line2"  

thus matches all in one row